# run Task as I type with linq(cancel previous Task if still running)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, task, cancellation-token

I want to make a Task that searches with linq as I type, and if the user types in another character, it should cancel the task and recreate the search,  I have the following code:

```
private Task SearchChannels;
private CancellationTokenSource cancelSearch;

public void PopulateChannels(string newValue)
{
    IsSearchingChannels = true; //This just shows a progressbar
    if (SearchChannels != null && cancelSearch!= null)
        if (SearchChannels.Status == TaskStatus.Running || 
            SearchChannels.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun || 
            SearchChannels.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation || 
            SearchChannels.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete) 
        {
            cancelSearch.Cancel();
            SearchChannels.Wait();
        }
    cancelSearch = new CancellationTokenSource();
    SearchChannels = new Task(() => Channels = new PagedObservableCollection<Channel>(ContractManager.Channels.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(newValue)).AsParallel().WithCancellation(cancelSearch.Token).ToList()), cancelSearch.Token); //PagedObservableCollection is just a simple class with a list that keeps all items and an ObservableCollection for current items shown

    SearchChannels.Start();
    SearchChannels.ContinueWith((continuation) => IsSearchingChannels = false); // this just hides the progressbar when done
}
```

I get this Exception:

An exception of type `'System.OperationCanceledException'` 
occurred in `System.Core.dll` but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The operation was canceled.

I am a bit of a beginner with tasks and cancellationTokens, can anyone guide me on the correct path from here?  I basically want the Task to check if its already running, cancel it, and run it again with the new value(I want to make this "SearchBox" function similar to visual studio's search in solution explorer, which searches as you type)

Comment: Have you taken a look at Rx.net `Buffer().Select(searchString => Observable.StartAsync(cancelToken => Search(searchString, cancelToken)).Switch()`

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Rx if there isn't another way, looks like a bit of a learning curve :) I tried your example, but I don't get how and where it should be used, also Buffer(). doesn't give me a method like select, what using should I use (i've added `using System.Reactive.Linq`)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to create an `IObservable<string>` to abstract the changing the value on your control. The "easiest" way to do this would be with a `Subject<string>`, but most likely its the wrong way to do it.

Below is the code you should put into your ViewModel.

```
IDisposable _searchSubscriber =
    _searchString
         .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMillisecond(300))
         .Select(searchString => 
                Observable.StartAsync(cancelToken => 
                      Search(searchString, cancelToken)
                ).Switch()
         .ObserveOn(new DispatcherScheduler())
         .Subscribe(results => Channels = results);

public Task<List<Channel>> Search(string searchTerm, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    var query = dbContext.Channels.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm));
    return query.ToListAsync(cancel);
}

private BehaviorSubject<string> _searchString = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
public string SearchString
{
    get { return _searchString.Value; }
    set { _searchString.OnNext(value); OnPropertyChanged("SearchString"); }
}
```

Rx.net is an extremely powerful library, which of course means it does have a bit of a learning curve (although the fact is this is complex because your problem is complex).

Let me lay it out...

`.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))` debounces your query, so it only runs the query once every 300 milliseconds.

`Observable.StartAsync(cancelToken => Search(searchString, cancelToken))` creates an Observable for the search task, which will be cancelled when it is disposed.

`Select(x => ...).Switch()` takes only the latest query results, and disposes the last query.

`ObserveOn(...)` run the following on the scheduler used, make sure you use either `DispatchScheduler` if you are using `WPF`, or `WinformsScheduler` if you use Winforms.

`Subscribe(results => ...)` do something with the results.

Comment: I query database objects, for example, get all records in the Channel table with Name field starting with 'ace'.  I am using `WPF` with `EntityFrameWork`, so basically my "SearchBox" is bound to a `ChannelSearchString` property in the viewmodel, with the setter calling the  `PopulateChannels(string newValue)` method  which needs to asynchronously query the database.  The listbox showing the search results is bound to a Channels property, which is changed every time `PopulateChannels` is called.

Comment: I dont have direct access to the dbContext, it is encapsulated in a repository (ContractManager), my problem is ToListAsync, the respository send the list as a IEnumerable(ObservableCollection) and not an IQueryable.  Do you know of another way besides changing the repository code? Thanks for all your help

Comment: @jclabuschagne We NEED to have Repo code that knows about async and cancellation. Which is what you WANTED to have supported.

Comment: @jclabuschagne you DO realise that each time your call ContractManager right now, you pull EVERY `Channel` object from the database right? You know that is really bad right?